# When Inserting data in Postgres, Why I am getting Undefined Column Error?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

When I am trying to insert data from a list of tuples which contains some None values , I am having the error as
**psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn:**

My code is :

```
id=[1,3,4,5]
name=['aryan','aman','vimlesh','kamla']
salary=[10000,3000,4000,1500]
manager_id=[3,4,None,None]
list_data=zip(id,name,salary,manager_id)
table_creation_query='create table employee (id int,name text,salary bigint,manager_id int)'
#cursor.execute(table_creation_query)
for i in list_data:
    query=f'insert into employee values {i}'
    cursor.execute(query)
```

I am getting this as error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/aryan/sample/SQL_Queries.py", line 177, in 
> cursor.execute(query)
> psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "none" does not exist
> LINE 1: insert into employee values (4, 'vimlesh', 4000, None)
> ^
> HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "employee.name"

But, when I am checking the postgres, tuple which does not contain the None values have been inserted [PostgresSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV7Q9.png)

I tried to give null values in the list but that was not suppported,

Comment: None is a piece of text, not a valid integer. Use NULL. By the way, it's cleaner to mention the column names in your INSERT statement

Comment: NULL is supported you are just doing the wrong thing by using `f` string interpolation. The correct procedure is to use [Parameter passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries), which not only takes care of type handling but also prevents SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

`None` is being passed as literal. instead you probably want to convert Python's `None` to SQL's `Null`. The recommended way to do that is to use SQL [parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/params.html).